# What happened to the Apple Device SBC that was supposed to compete with the linux SBCs?

Tags: apple-macintosh

I am not sure if this question is "on topic" or not, but I'm asking it anyway...

I was reading Hackaday.com a few months ago and I came across this article: https://hackaday.com/2016/04/01/apple-introduces-their-answer-to-the-raspberry-pi/

Nautraly, I thought that it was pretty cool, so I went to buy a unit, but I can't find at all, anywhere.There is nothing on Apple's website; There's nothing on google, duckduckgo, eBay, or Amazon. The only place that I ever saw it was on Hackaday.This makes me think its vapourwear?
Does anyone know different?

Comment: You did notice that the date of the Hackaday article was April 1st? I guess you fell for it...

Comment: This isn't on-topic. It might be on-topic on [Apple.se], but I'm not sure how useful this question would be to that site.

Answer (score 3):

It is an [April Fool's Day](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/April_Fools%27_Day) article.

[https://hackaday.com/ **2016/04/01** /apple-introduces-their-answer-to-the-raspberry-pi/](https://hackaday.com/2016/04/01/apple-introduces-their-answer-to-the-raspberry-pi/)

Comment: Ok thanks. Shoot! That was a great prank! Now I feel stupid, but they did a good job faking that.